# How to manage parsing an null object for DateTime to be used with ADO.NET as DBNULL

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, ado.net, dbnull

I have two DateTime objects, BirthDate and HireDate. They are correctly formatted as a string and when I pass them through to my data access layer, they need to be parsed into a DateTime object.

```
DateTime hD = DateTime.Parse(hire);            
DateTime bD = DateTime.Parse(birth);

//incase of a datestring being passed through
dateStringPassed = "7/2/1969";
```

But sometimes, the strings `hire` and `birth` are null or empty `""`, if the code is run like this, I get a FormatException error from Parsing a empty string. How can I manage empty parses and allow the DateTime, if empty or null, be accepted as `DBNull.Value`?

I still cannot manage incase the user does not pass through a DateTime string, then the parse crashes my code.

My parameter for birth date is as follows and checks the variable if null, then use DBNull.Value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) date times - the shortcut syntax would be `DateTime?` (note the `?` at the end).

```
DateTime? hD = null;
if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(hire )) // string.IsNullOrEmpty if on .NET pre 4.0
{
   hD = DateTime.Parse(hire);            
}
```

You can test for `hD.HasValue` and if it doesn't use `DbNull.Value` instead.

Comment: Can you write an example with DateTime bD = DateTime.Parse(birth)? Will using a `?` at the end work also for an `int`?

Comment: @GivenPie - Yes, it would for an `int` and any value type.

Comment: Hey Oded, I've called the `.HasValue` like this: `.Value = bD.HasValue ? DBNull.Value : (object)bD;` and my debugger is telling me this Parameter has no Default value. What do you think this means?

Comment: You are setting `.Value` to `DBNull.Value` if _there is_ a value and passing `null` if not. You need to flip the two results to `.Value = bD.HasValue ? (object)bD : DBNull.Value;`

Answer (score 22):

The `Parse` method  can't handle empty strings, but you can use nullable DateTime and do something like this:

```
DateTime? hD = String.IsNullOrEmpty(hire) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(hire)
```

But even safer would be using `TryParse` instead:

```
DateTime? hD = null;
DateTime.TryParse(hire, out hD);
```

Then for storing this value, you can test `hD.HasValue`:

```
if(hD.HasValue) { /* use hD */ }
else { /* else use DBNull.Value */ }
```

---

Since C# 7, you can use shorter syntax for inline out parameters and you can avoid nullable type altogether:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(hire, out var hD)) { /* use hD */ }
else { /* use DBNull.Value */ }
```

Comment: I believe you will have to cast the `null` in that ternary operator in order to get that line to compile. Both sides of the `:` need to be of the same type or types that have implicit conversions between them.

Comment: And that last line - I don't see how you could cast that so the compiler can accept it.

Comment: Agreed, tryParse is super useful here to avoid additional if checks and keep code cleaner

Answer (score 1):

If you use this method, any thing that is not a correct date will return a `DBNull.Value`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Parses a date string and returns
/// a DateTime if it is a valid date,
/// if not returns DBNull.Value
/// </summary>
/// <param name="date">Date string</param>
/// <returns>DateTime or DBNull.Value</returns>
public static object CreateDBDateTime(string date)
{
    DateTime result;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    return DBNull.Value;
}
```